# Angular2 and tomcat 8 : CORS automatically sends a OPTION request instead of POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat, cors, jersey

I trying out angular2 so I'm newbie. 
I have a tomcat 8 with jersey server already working, I'm still using it with android application without any kind of problem.
So when I try to implement a simple POST request to server with angular2 it is failing due to CORS not allowed. 
I have added allow-cross-origins headers in angular request. This is the code:

```
 var creds = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
   let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
   headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
   this.http.post("http://192.168.1.70:9000/api/login", creds, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => this.saveJwt(data),
            err => this.logError(err),
            () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
        );
```

And on server side i added filter on tomacat 8 web.xml file.

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

What is wrong with this? 
I understood that the problem is the browser security policy, but I only have to do a simple test of CRUD application in localhost, with tomcat running on localhost:9000 and angular apllication running on localhost:3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the `headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` line.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is a server response header. If you add it to a request, it’ll cause the browser to send a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), exactly as you’re seeing.